# Arduino and temperature sensor

Tags: arduino

hello i want to do a project using an arduino and a temperature sensor. let a certain temperature value be determined.when this value is exceeded, 1.if the engine temperature value is lower than the set value, 2.start the engine. what kind of scheme and coding should I do for this?

I want to know where to start

Comment: There's thousands related topics on web. example here https://mechatrofice.com/arduino/arduino-temperature-controller . Learn and try by yourself, and comme back here with your code if problem.

Answer (score 0):

well here's some steps for you:

1. Learn Programming (Algorithm, Syntax, etc)
2. Learn Basic Arduino
3. Learn to Read the Sensor Data
4. Modify your code by adding "if" statement so you can achieve what you want

I guess your code would looked like this:

```
#include <library of the sensor if any>

int sensorPin = the number of the pin being used by the sensor;

void setup(){
    pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT); // a sensor is an input device
    //so we set the pin to be an input pin
}

void loop(){
    float sensor_value;
    sensor_value = algorithm to measure the temp;

    if (sensor_value < set value){
        //code to start the engine
    } else {
        //code to stop the engine
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you need a relay to start or terminate the engine. Here's some references that might helps:

https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-for-ds18b20-temperature-sensor-with-arduino/

https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-relay